# Live data builder

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I am trying to understand live data builder. From what I have figured out you need to give corutine context, timeout and suspend function to create a live data.

The default value for corutine context is Dispatcher.Main (UI thread). And timeout is 5 seconds.

This is code I found in [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata)

```
val user: LiveData<User> = liveData {
    val data = database.loadUser() // loadUser is a suspend function.
    emit(data)
}
```

Now my question is how can we can db or network call on Dispatcher.Main

Comment: Well behaved suspending functions don't block the caller. For example if your database is created using room then declaring a suspending function in dao does cause it to switch dispatcher internally.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm does this means. Kotlin with coroutine on single thread environment can behave like node js frame work.